# When I issue the zfold2 screenshot command connected using adb, a black screen appears

Tags: adb

When I issue the zfold2 screenshot command connected using adb, a black screen appears.

First, I checked whether the adb connection was normal.

I entered 'adb devices' in cmd and it is connected normally as follows.

172.30.1.2:5555        device

Next, I tried

scrcpy -s 172.30.1.2:5555 -m 1100 -S --window-x 350 --window-y 710

opened normally

```
adb -s 172.30.1.2:5555 shell screencap -p /sdcard/Pictures/Screenshots/screenshot.png
adb -s 172.30.1.2:5555 pull /sdcard/Pictures/Screenshots/screenshot.png C:\Users\Weed
```

result
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mc4P4.jpg)

I took a screenshot and brought it to my phone, but all I got was a black screen.
Is there a solution?

Comment: adb -s 172.30.1.2:5555 exec-out screencap -p > C:\Users\Weed\screenshot.png

This code also produces the same result.

Comment: Please don't use screenshots for terminal output. Anyway the screenshot doesn't show anything on my system (only black picture). Just copy and paste the terminal output as text into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Is your phone lock screen on? If so, unlock(or disable lock) and try again.

Comment: I unlocked it and tried it. But it's the same.